# Custom log4j plugin and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, log4j, log4j2

I have a custom log4j layout plugin I want to use. When running in IntelliJ or with `./gradlew bootRun` the plugin works fine. Building a boot jar with `./gradlew bootJar` does not.

Enabling `-Dlog4j.debug=true` reveals that in IntelliJ and `bootRun` uses sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader, whereas the jar uses org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.

Digging in the logs reveals the following, from the working:

```
INFO StatusLogger Scanning for classes in '/home/rohdef/.m2/repository/dk/rohdef/logging/log4j/0.4.5-SNAPSHOT/log4j-0.4.5-SNAPSHOT.jar' matching criteria annotated with @Plugin
DEBUG StatusLogger Checking to see if class dk.rohdef.logging.log4j.CustomLog4jLayout matches criteria annotated with @Plugin
DEBUG StatusLogger Checking to see if class dk.rohdef.logging.log4j.context.Log4jDiagnosticContext matches criteria annotated with @Plugin
DEBUG StatusLogger Checking to see if class dk.rohdef.logging.log4j.CustomLog4jLayout$1 matches criteria annotated with @Plugin
DEBUG StatusLogger Checking to see if class dk.rohdef.logging.log4j.CustomLog4jLayout$Builder matches criteria annotated with @Plugin
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0.009241 seconds to load 1 plugins from package dk.enettet.rohdef.log4j
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 118 plugins
```

whereas the jar logs:

```
INFO StatusLogger Scanning for classes in '/home/rohdef/git/foo-backend/foo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' matching criteria annotated with @Plugin
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0.158622 seconds to load 0 plugins from package dk.rohdef.logging.log4j
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 117 plugins
```

`log4j-0.4.5-SNAPSHOT.jar` is inside the `foo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` as expected.

This leads me to suspect that the way LaunchedURLClassLoader is the source of the error. Am I correct in that? If so is this a bug or am I using it wrong? How do I make my plugin work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andy Wilkinson from gitter provided the answer:

It sounds to me like Log4j is making assumptions about the structure of the jar files that it finds on the classpath that do not hold true with using a fat jar with jars nested in `BOOT-INF/lib`.

You could use `requiresUnpack` so that the fat jar automatically unpacks your `log4j-0.4.5-SNAPSHOT.jar` so that it's available directly on the filesystem from where Log4j should be able to scan it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-unpacking